# Store DOM element content in variable, and update the same DOM element with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given the following DOM element:

```
<span class=itemNumber>10</span>
```

I want to store the number in a variable, transform it to an integer, add 1 to it, and then update it in the DOM.

I tried to do it with this function, bound to a click event:

```
var itemCount = parseInt($('.itemNumber').text())+1;
$('.itemNumber').html(itemCount);
```

Seems simple enough, but the result is not what I'm expecting. Instead of replacing the old "10" number with "11", it displays "1011". I tried using .empty() function before the .html(), but it's the same result.

I suspect the variable is not actually storing the number, but a reference to the element.

Any ideas?

Comment: this code is valid, find the problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly valid through. But this is a typical usage of **[text(func)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)** syntax.

```
$('.itemNumber').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function (_, val) {
        return +val + 1;
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LhE9y/)**

Your issue could be that you have more than 1, `.itemnumber` and not using `$(this)` inthe handler could cause the selection of both. and `$('.itemNumber').text()` will give you both the numbers together(innertext of both of them) say `1010` and it will increment it by `1` and you get the result as `1011` instead of `11`.

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/a4ry4/

So your fix would be to use the clicked instance alone in your handler to select the text.

```
var itemCount = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)+1;
$(this).html(itemCount);
```

Comment: @gdoron Right.. But his code should work as well. eventhough radix is not specified in parse int.

Comment: Yes, I know it should work, so if it doesn't work, yours will probably won't work either...

Comment: @gdoron see my answer uipdate.

Comment: This was my hunch as well.

Comment: @gdoron all based on assumptions.. lets see what OP has to say.. I couldn't find another scenario.

Comment: You are absolutely right; I had duplicated elements. I feel like a total idiot. I was busting my head for hours with this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function can take a mutator function:

```
$('.itemNumber').text(function(_, txt) {
    return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Not sure what it is - at first I thought it was a problem treating a number as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert itemCount to a string before using it as the item's text.

```
$('.itemNumber').text(itemCount.toString());
```